# C program not reading .dat file from command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have the following program called `Scorecommandline`:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc!=15) {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }

    int iArray[14];
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        if(scanf("%d",&iArray[i]) != 1){
        break;
        }
        i++;
        if(i == 14) {
        i = 0;
        }
    }

    int age = atoi(iArray[1]);
    int b_AF = atoi(iArray[2]);
    int b_ra = atoi(iArray[3]);
    int b_renal = atoi(iArray[4]);
    int b_treatedhyp = atoi(iArray[5]);
    int b_type2 = atoi(iArray[6]);
    double bmi = atof(iArray[7]);
    int ethrisk = atoi(iArray[8]);
    int fh_cvd = atoi(iArray[9]);
    double rati = atof(iArray[10]);
    double sbp = atof(iArray[11]);
    int smoke_cat = atoi(iArray[12]);
    int surv = atoi(iArray[13]);
    double town = atof(iArray[14]);

    double score = cvd_femal(age,b_AF,b_ra,b_renal,b_treatedhyp,b_type2,bmi,ethrisk,fh_cvd,rati,sbp,smoke_cat,surv,town,&error,errorBuf,sizeof(errorBuf));
    if (error) {
        printf("%s", errorBuf);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%f\n", score);
}
```

in which I have a .dat file intended to be used for the args in this program, however if I type:

```
cat testscandata.dat | ./ScorecommandLine
```

the program does not read the file in as the parameters for the program. How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `./ScorecommandLine < testscandata.dat`?

Comment: You are scanning everything into an array of ints and then you try and convert these ints from strings to... ints?

Comment: @bash0r - unfortunately that gives me the same thing - just waits for user input

Comment: @dreamlax It's still the better way to pipe files as input and I guess templatetypedef answered the Question. :)

Comment: @dreamlax very good point, have taken out all atoi calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing two different ways of passing input into a program.  You can pass arguments to `main` in a program by invoking the command from the command-line and listing the arguments.  For example:

```
./ScoreCommandLine 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

These arguments will be passed into `main` through `argv`.

You can also pipe input into a program by sending in data through `stdin` by using pipes and redirection:

```
SomeCommand | ./ScoreCommandLine
```

This will take the output of `SomeCommand` and use that as the `stdin` stream in `ScoreCommandLine`.  You can read it by using `scanf`, etc.

In your case, you should either rewrite the program so that you aren't expecting all the arguments to be passed in through the command-line, or you should use the `xargs` utility to convert `stdin` into command-line arguments:

```
xargs ./ScoreCommandLine < testscandata.dat
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This will not be passed as arguments to the program, but it will be piped into `stdin` of the `./ScorecommandLine` program - you will be able to read it through `scanf` and similar functions, but not as command line arguments.

You need to create new script which will read file (or `stdin`) and it will execute another program passing it as executable arguments.

After examing your program, I can suggest removing `if (argc!=15)`, since you are reading `stdin` with `scanf`, and not parsing command line arguments anywhere.